# switching inductive load using ESP8266

Tags: relay, esp8266, induction-motor

I have ESP8266 and I want to turn off/on my 1hp-compressor-water-pump.
How can I trigger my motor using ESP8266, what component should I use to on/off my motor. I don't want to use 12V (relay uses 12V), I have 3Vdc, 220Vac.
Some of component I know used for switching:
BT136-triac
JQC-3FC(T73)DC12V - relay
MCB

Motor Spec:
[image]

In short how to on/off, inductive motor, using 3v or less

@EJE

Comment: How does this differ from your last question?

Comment: After many BTA16 blowing, I thought of buying the SSR but this video helped me that SSR may also fail, and it requires min 4V, but I want coil voltage 2-3V https://youtu.be/2UtL2uAYCUA

Comment: I think, zero crossing may be key, I have read about ZC, there's no shortcut.